# image_downloader plugin not compiling on latest kotlin version

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-dependencies

I have recently updated my ext.kotlin_version from 1.7.x to 1.8.22 and the plugin image_downloader throws the following error during compilation for android:

```
file:*/image_downloader-0.31.0/android/src/main/kotlin/com/ko2ic/ima
gedownloader/ImageDownloaderPlugin.kt:332:17 'when' expression must be exhaustive, add necessary 'is Pending','is Successful' branches or 'else' branch instead


Execution failed for task ':image_downloader:compileDebugKotlin'.
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue seems to occur as the version on github has not yet been published to pub. Therefore a temporary fix for this is to add the direct git url to fetch the latest version from git

```
  image_downloader:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/ko2ic/image_downloader
```

Current version on pub is image_downloader: ^0.31.0, while git includes image_downloader: ^0.32.0